# How do I create an alias that displays the contents of a `history list`?

Tags: bashrc, alias

How do I create a new alias command called `cet103demo` which displays the contents of 
the bash history list one page at a time, and also making sure the new alias is automatically loaded when the virtual machine starts up?

Answer (score 6):

Fairly simple. Just run the following in a terminal:

```
echo 'alias cet103demo="history | more"' >> ~/.bash_aliases
source ~/.bash_aliases
cet103demo  # to test
```

You'll only have to run these once to remove it, you'll just need to edit `~/.bash_aliases` (it'll be the last line).

Comment: Isn't it better to put aliases in `~/.bash_aliases` than in `~/.bashrc`, though it does matter technically, just to organize things better?

Comment: @Jobin Probably, yeah.

Comment: So i would open Gedit add #!/bin/bash and paste in "echo 'alias cet103demo="history | more"' >> ~/.bash_aliases
source ~/.bash_aliases' " under neath ??

Comment: @user264934 No. You must to open the [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal) and run those commands inside of.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line to your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
alias cet103demo="history | more"
```

And just hit <kbd>SPACE</kbd> to page down